# Fade in Fade out effect for Text Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a plugin which makes the text fade in and out in wordpress, and I'm trying to change the code as it goes from white to black, I want it to go from white to transparent, tried to change the fade in and fade out codes, but didn't work

here is the JS

```
var FadeIn_FadeInterval;

window.onload = FadeIn_FadeRotate

var FadeIn_Links;
var FadeIn_Titles;
var FadeIn_Cursor = 0;
var FadeIn_Max;


function FadeIn_FadeRotate() 
{
  FadeIn_FadeInterval = setInterval(FadeIn_Ontimer, 10);
  FadeIn_Links = new Array();
  FadeIn_Titles = new Array();
  FadeIn_SetFadeLinks();
  FadeIn_Max = FadeIn_Links.length-1;
  FadeIn_SetFadeLink();
}

function FadeIn_SetFadeLink() {
  var ilink = document.getElementById("FadeIn_Link");
  ilink.innerHTML = FadeIn_Titles[FadeIn_Cursor];
  ilink.href = FadeIn_Links[FadeIn_Cursor];
}

function FadeIn_Ontimer() {
  if (FadeIn_bFadeOutt) {
    FadeIn_Fade+=FadeIn_FadeStep;
    if (FadeIn_Fade>FadeIn_FadeOut) {
      FadeIn_Cursor++;
      if (FadeIn_Cursor>FadeIn_Max)
        FadeIn_Cursor=0;
      FadeIn_SetFadeLink();
      FadeIn_bFadeOutt = false;
    }
  } else {
    FadeIn_Fade-=FadeIn_FadeStep;
    if (FadeIn_Fade<FadeIn_FadeIn) {
      clearInterval(FadeIn_FadeInterval);
      setTimeout(Faderesume, FadeIn_FadeWait);
      FadeIn_bFadeOutt=true;
    }
  }
  var ilink = document.getElementById("FadeIn_Link");
  if ((FadeIn_Fade<FadeIn_FadeOut)&&(FadeIn_Fade>FadeIn_FadeIn))
    ilink.style.color = "#" + ToHex(FadeIn_Fade);
}

function Faderesume() {
  FadeIn_FadeInterval = setInterval(FadeIn_Ontimer, 10);
}

function ToHex(strValue) {
  try {
    var result= (parseInt(strValue).toString(16));

    while (result.length !=2)
            result= ("0" +result);
    result = result + result + result;
    //alert(result);
    return result.toUpperCase();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
  }
}
```

and this is the php code for it

and the codes are as follows

Fade out : 255
Fade in: 0
fade: 0

I've tried to change the numbers but it stops working

Comment: Can you post a working example with HTML or what you did so far?

Comment: Transparent isn't a hex color.

Comment: Google for `transition css` and you can implement if for the color attribute - It should be from `rgba(255,255,255,1)` to `rgba(255,255,255,0)`

Comment: @AlonEitan, I would but the idea is that I'm using this to change text, this is the plugin url http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/04/22/wordpress-plugin-wp-fadein-text-news/

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane: it can be, if you accept that any colour with an opacity of 0 is 'transparent.' It's not supported in all browsers, but there is an `rgba` syntax using hex, for example transparent white: `#fff0` (or, long form: `#ffffff00`). (Simple demo: https://jsfiddle.net/quf36ynr/).

Comment: Ok, I've removed the hex conversion code, it doesn't go to black now, but no fade effect, it only does transition to the next text

Comment: @JoeyArnanzo Changing color using JS seem like a waste of time when you can do so much with pure css, [for example](http://jsfiddle.net/jk3c2hyt/) - But it's very hard to understand the problem without a full [mcve] with the HTML and CSS included in the question